# Transfer bounty points

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I believe If I could transfer points specifically to use for bounties (only for bounties) from
sisters sites (like stackoverflow) to other sites, **just for the sake** of opening bounties, I would have used this a lot. As, for example, I need stuff especially from serverfault, as answers there tend to save a lot of time.
You might suggest I participate and answer stuff...sadly, I am not that expert on server issues.

[edit]=I removed the part on buying as I am convinced it is not "worth it".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow bounty to be set with reputation from another site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7193/allow-bounty-to-be-set-with-reputation-from-another-site)

Answer (score 3):

It adds complexity for something that I don't believe is necessary. Also - as we already discussed ad nauseum - "buying" points (even if they can only be used for bounties) is against the spirit of the websites.

Comment: @Kop ...there is also the second part of my suggestion. Besides, it is like open source, you can get everything for free, but also some payed support, is it not in spirit?

Comment: It's spelled `paid`; and no it's not the same as "open source". I answered to the second part of your suggestion with "It adds complexity for something that I don't believe is necessary"

Answer (score 2):

I can understand the wish to buy bounty points, but in addition to buying points for money being against the basic spirit of the trilogy, money transfer would pose enormous (and expensive) technical and tax obstacles for negligeable amounts of money that would never yield any kind of profit. Simply can't be done.

The idea of transferring points from associated accounts on sister sites, though, I find very good, and I can't see any obvious possibilities of abuse.

Answer (score 0):

Every time I visit the paper towel department, I see a collection of questions that have perfectly valid, reasonable, not-accepted answers. 'Bounty'-land seems, at least on so.com, to be the home of people unwilling to accept the necessary non-squareness of circles. So I'm -1 on expending any effort on anything related to bounties.

Comment: I totally disagree with this notion. Bounties can be a great way to gain exposure for a question, and an incentive to take a deeper look into an issue - not primarily for the stupid *points*, but because the asker is ready to *give up something*. I frequently ask bounty questions when a good answer would help me massively in my daily work, or when I want to get as many views and opinions as possible on a question. The fact that they are used by some who are unwilling to accept the reality that their question is not answerable in a way they find satisfying does not devalue bounties as such.

Comment: @Pekka obviously, our mileages have varied. The few times I've offered a bounty, nothing happened.